# Can I use windscreen repair resin in wet weather?

Tags: repair, windshield

I have a small pit in my windscreen, and a DIY repair kit (using UV cured resin and a syringe to make a vaccum. I'm in the UK, and its wet at the moment (but also cold, so I really want to get this fixed).

The resin is marked as containing methacrylates, and the instructions caution about using in hot conditions or bright sunlight. How important is it that the crack is dry before applying the resin?

Comment: You might regret spending time on this, with hindsight. I once had a stone-chipped screen, and the screen replacement company said "you don't need a new screen for that, we can repair the old one". After waiting a couple of hours for them to do the job, the result was a worse mess than the original chip, so I waited longer for the new screen I originally asked for! (At least they didn't charge me for the failed attempt at a repair).

Comment: @alephzero -  On the other hand I had a small chip in the lower part of my windshield that the shop refused to repair because it was "in the line of sight", even though the only thing it was in the line of sight of was the far end of the hood. They wanted to sell me a full windshield replacement. I bought a home repair kit and repaired it myself, and 5 years later, it's still barely noticeable.

Comment: @alephzero Its only a small chip, barely noticeable. I just want to avoid it getting any worse through ice damage. I've used these repair kits before with no problem.

Answer (score 3):

The windshield should be dry when using the repair resin according to [Popular Mechanics](http://www.popularmechanics.com/cars/how-to/a77/easy-windshield-repair/). Also, it should be near the room temperature. If it is cold and/or wet, you can use a hair dryer to heat up the location of the windshield you're planning to repair, and also to make it dry.

So, in practice you need access to electricity for performing your repair.

If it's continuously raining, I wouldn't attempt to repair it, as there is no way to make it dry. Instead, wait for the rain to stop.